Puppet not downloading file from https source if target file doesn't exist and checksum_value is set
I have situation where puppet doesn't even bother downloading file if it doesn't exist. Calculated sha256 for it to avoid constantly downloading and updating if the file has not changed and entered it into puppet manifest. Code used is roughly something like that:
class download_haproxy_promethus_exporter () {
  file { '/usr/sbin/haproxy_exporter':
    ensure         => file,
    owner          => 'root',
    group          => 'root',
    mode           => '0755',
    source         => 'https://exporters.intra.network/haproxy_exporter',
    checksum       => 'sha256',
    checksum_value => '7abaa0d0de96b313b81613fc4030b6fcd3cbe2777b91d86aae910488c4a385f6'
  }
}

Puppet 7.x.x is used and AlmaLinux if that makes any difference.
If I have created the file and checksum doesn't match, then it will download the file. I know there is workaround to this by creating exec that will just touch the file and will have "creates" parameter, but why would I need to go through such hurdle if file resource is supposed to ensure file exists. Not sure if it will skip file resource when exec has creates flag on it.
I would have guessed that puppet will try to ensure the file exists and no file would mean that checksum check fails and it will be downloaded from the source and then permissions corrected.

Try using present instead of file ? https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/file.html#file-attribute-ensure
